# How do I open or create word documents in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, download, doc

I have a form on my CodeIgniter app that has users uploading doc files to a directory on my server.  I need to be able to open these files from the app.  I am trying to create a method that downloads these files so that I can open them in a word processor.  No errors display on my method's output(php errors), but the files do not come out correctly in open office.  There are 217 pages in the downloaded file(it should really only have 3 pages) and they are filled with random characters.

Example:

```
ÐÏ#à¡±#á################;###þÿ  #################<###################þÿÿÿ########ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿýÿÿÿÿÿÿÿþÿÿÿþÿÿÿ################   ###
#######
```

So this is what I have for my controller method.

```
function downloadresume($filename, $ext){

        $this->load->helper('download');
        $this->load->helper('file');

        $content = read_file('./_resumes/'.$filename.'.'.$ext);
        force_download($filename.'.'.$ext, $content);

    }
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Am I missing something?

Comment: have you tried setting the header , mimetypes, etc. this could also affect the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at http://phpword.codeplex.com/ I have used it in several projects and it seems to work very well. You will need to write a bridging library so you can use it but that is really not so difficult.

I hope this helps, good luck